# How to read a XML file with a "Unexpected XML declaration"?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

My code for reading an XML file in a zip file:

"**ZipPathListSize**" is the number of the zip files, **@ZipPathList[i]** is an string array has every zip file path, and the "**modDesc / modDesc.xml**" is the XML file's fixed name in every zip file.

```
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Xml;
--------------------------------------------
for (int i = 0; i < ZipPathListSize; i++)
{
    using (ZipArchive ZipFileContent = ZipFile.OpenRead(@ZipPathList[i]))
    {
        XmlDocument ModDesc = new();
        ZipArchiveEntry Entry = ZipFileContent.GetEntry("modDesc.xml");
        if (Entry != null)
        {
            using (Stream stream = Entry.Open())
            {
                bool ExFlag = false;
                try
                {
                    ModDesc.Load(stream);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(@ZipPathList[i] + ex));
                    ExFlag = true;
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (ExFlag == false)
                    {
                        XmlNode MVersion = ModDesc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/modDesc");
                        int Version = Convert.ToInt16(MVersion.Attributes["descVersion"].InnerText);
                        //MessageBox.Show(@ZipPathList[i] + Version); //DEBUG ONLY
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Not A Mod");   //DEBUG ONLY
        }
    }
}
```

The question is, some of the XML files (modDesc.xml) in zip files didn't have a correct declaration. Such as:

Empty first line

```
<!-- This is an empty line (Line 1), in the origin file -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no" ?> <!-- Here is Line 2 -->
<modDesc descVersion="61">
...
```

or Wrong version

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no" ?> <!-- 1.1? Really? -->
<modDesc descVersion="62">
```

but all other parts of those XMLs are correct.

How can I read an XML with the wrong declaration? Maybe somehow ignore the format checking and force it to read nodes and attributes?

**By the way, I can not modify any XML files manually or fix them in a non-programming way.**

**So, no vscode, no notepad++ :(**

```
System.Xml.XmlException: The XML declaration must be the first node in the document, and no whitespace characters are allowed to appear before it. Line 2, position 3.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String arg)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParsePI(StringBuilder piInDtdStringBuilder)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadNode(Boolean skipOverWhitespace)
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadDocSequence(XmlDocument parentDoc)
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean preserveWhitespace)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(Stream inStream)
   at FS22_ModManagerCore.ListMods.ByModFolder(String ModFolder) in 
.....ListMods.cs:line 37
```

---

```
System.Xml.XmlException: Version number '1.1' is invalid. Line 1, position 16.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String arg)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseXmlDeclaration(Boolean isTextDecl)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean preserveWhitespace)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(Stream inStream)
   at FS22_ModManagerCore.ListMods.ByModFolder(String ModFolder) in 
......ListMods.cs:line 37
```

Comment: "1.1? Really?" - XML 1.1 is absolutely a thing. I wish it were more widely supported :(

Comment: [XmlDocument.Validate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.validate?view=net-6.0) check this out.

Comment: @Trevor The Exception happened on "ModDesc.Load(stream);", I can't validate an XML before it has been loaded.

Comment: The empty first line is easy enough to fix with the String.Trim() function.  How are you representing the XML in memory?  Is it simply a string?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I can't make a workaround for every type of "Unexpected XML declaration." So I'm looking for a more general way to ignore/bypass declaration checking. I can't oversee what unexpected declaration will come next.

Comment: You don't have to treat every problem individually,  just replace the XML declaration with the "right" one.

Comment: Implementing a mini-parser to read the stream up to the end of the declaration (if present) so the XML parser proper never sees it is not particularly complicated. If you don't care about strictly catching all invalid XML you can make it as simple as scanning for the first `<`, checking if there's a `?`, and if so, keep on reading until you see `?>`. Repeat until no more declarations, and rewind the stream one character (or wrap the stream with your own and emit an extra `<` if you must handle streams that absolutely cannot be rewound). No, there is no "ignore junk" setting out of the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for now, I've already fixed this issue by myself, and I'll post my code here for general reference.

To fix the XML declaration issue, first I `Dispose()` the `ZipArchive ZipFileContent = ZipFile.OpenRead(@ZipPathList[i])` and re-open it in `ZipArchiveMode.Update`.

Then load all text from modDesc.xml into `string[] AllTextInLine`.

After that, delete and recreate the modDesc.xml using `ErrorZipContent.CreateEntry("modDesc.xml")`.

Finally, write the correct first line (declaration) to the new modDesc.xml and write the rest of `AllTextInLine[]`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < ZipPathListSize; i++)
{
    using (ZipArchive ZipFileContent = ZipFile.OpenRead(@ZipPathList[i]))
    {
        XmlDocument ModDesc = new();
        ZipArchiveEntry NormalEntry = ZipFileContent.GetEntry("modDesc.xml");
        if (NormalEntry != null)
        {
            Stream NormalStream = NormalEntry.Open();
            bool ExFlag = false;
            try
            {
                ModDesc.Load(NormalStream);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ExFlag = true;
                MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(@ZipPathList[i] + "\n\n" + ex));
                Clipboard.SetText(Convert.ToString(@ZipPathList[i] + "\n\n" + ex));
                MessageBox.Show("Try to fix" + "\n\n" + @ZipPathList[i]);
                //ReplaceXmlDeclaration
                ZipFileContent.Dispose();
                using (ZipArchive ErrorZipContent = ZipFile.Open(@ZipPathList[i], ZipArchiveMode.Update))
                {
                    ZipArchiveEntry ErrorZipEntry = ErrorZipContent.GetEntry("modDesc.xml");
                    string[] AllTextInLine;
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(ErrorZipEntry.Open()))
                    {
                        AllTextInLine = Convert.ToString(reader.ReadToEnd()).Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\r", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                    }
                    //MessageBox.Show(AllTextInLine[0] + AllTextInLine[1] + AllTextInLine[2]);  //DEBUG ONLY
                    string Declaration = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" standalone=\"no\" ?>";
                    if (AllTextInLine[0] != Declaration)
                    {
                        ErrorZipEntry.Delete();
                        ErrorZipEntry = ErrorZipContent.CreateEntry("modDesc.xml");
                        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(ErrorZipEntry.Open()))
                        {
                            writer.WriteLine(Declaration);                  //Line 1
                            MessageBox.Show(@ZipPathList[i]);               //DEBUG ONLY
                            for (int j = 1; j < AllTextInLine.Length; j++)  //Start with Line 2 (Index j=1)
                            {
                                if (!AllTextInLine[j].Trim().StartsWith("<?"))
                                {
                                    writer.WriteLine(AllTextInLine[j]);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    ExFlag = false;
                    try
                    {
                        ModDesc.Load(ErrorZipEntry.Open());
                    }
                    catch (Exception exagain)
                    {
                        ExFlag = true;
                        MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(exagain));
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (ExFlag == false)
                {
                    XmlNode MVersion = ModDesc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/modDesc");
                    int Version = Convert.ToInt16(MVersion.Attributes["descVersion"].InnerText);
                    //MessageBox.Show(@ZipPathList[i] + Version);         //DEBUG ONLY
                    //if (i == ZipPathListSize - 1)                       //.
                    //{                                                   //.
                    //    MessageBox.Show(@ZipPathList[i] + Version);     //.
                    //}                                                   //DEBUG ONLY
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Fix Attempt Filed");
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Not A Mod");   //DEBUG ONLY
        }
    }
}
```